# Unity Too many animations too slow

Tags: unity-game-engine, animator

I'm making a match game and i have 9*7 grid, and each grid has animation when the game is over, but when i try to run the animation in each grid at the end the frame rate is becoming too slow. If i run only one animation like this

```
gridsMatrix[0,0].GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = true;
```

it's smooth, but with all the grid it's becoming so slow, any ideas how to get more frame rate
Also I have used Coroutines

```
 IEnumerator<float> ScaleDownGrid(GameObject grid) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            grid.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(  grid.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.x-1.5f,   grid.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.y-1.5f);   
            yield return 0f;
        }
    }
```

but did not help

Thanks

Comment: You're making a lot of redundant calls to `grid.GetComponent<RectTransform>()`. While it might not matter much, it certainly wouldn't hurt to cache the result.